# Вывод окна ожидания

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, dialog

Хочу вывести Alert окно, которое будет закрываться после того как выполнится задача из другого класса.

```
 @FXML
private void countAll() {
    if (checks.checkAll(dateFrom, dateTo, choiceBox.getValue())) {
        int id = checks.choiceID(choiceBox.getValue());
        try {
            ForThread forThread = new ForThread();
            forThread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ошибка");
        }
    }
}

 class ForThread implements Runnable{
    Thread thrd;

    @Override
    public void run() {
            mylert.setTitle(null); 
            mylert.setHeaderText(null);
            mylert.setResizable(false);
            mylert.show(); // тут вызываю алерт окно. 
            doSomethingExecutableMethod(); //этот метод выполняется очень медленно
            mylert.close();
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Thread started");
        if (thrd == null) {
            thrd= new Thread(this);
            thrd.start();
        }
    }
```

если нажимаю ОК(т.е. закрываю это алерт окно кнопкой из нее), до выполнения долгого метода, то ошибки нет. если жду пока сработает mylert.close(); то получаю следующую ошибку.

> Not on FX application thread;

Как я понял, этот ранейбл метод не имеет права трогать фрейм приложения. 
у меня задача вывести алерт, который будет висеть пока не выполнится долгий метод, таким образом дает знать, что метод еще не выполнился...

Comment: `Platform.runLater(...)` отправит проблемную строчку в FX поток.

Comment: Можно какой нибудь пример, т.к. то как я понимаю, произойдет тоже самое.

Comment: Вы написали, что ваш `ForThread` не имеет права трогать фрейм приложения. `Runnable` из `Platform.runLater` такие права имеет.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. получилось!